# How to correct Chrome wrong text rendering?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, frontend

I'm developing a wordpress website, i have defined the hn titles in the theme options. For example: h5 has a **font-weight: 300;**. 
But chrome windows renders it wrongly, it renders it as **font-weight:bold;** (it's ok on chrome mac). 
I even tried to change it via the inspector to see from where the problem came, but nothing changed.

Here's some pictures to show you the deference:

Chrome Windows (how it shouldn't be)

[image: Chrome Windrows]

FireFox Windows (how it should be)

[image: Firefox Windows]

Answer (score 0):

Please add code snippet.
I think you should use normalizer
[Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add font-face for custom font weights:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight: 300;
font-style: normal;
src: url("Roboto-Light.ttf") format("opentype"); }
```